# 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'... I cannot solve this error

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

My app was running good but when add fetchproducts() method thers is an error
'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

```
  Future<void> fetchProducts() async {
    const url = 'https://flutter-app-example-max.firebaseio.com/products.json';
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final jsonData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      if (jsonData == null) {
        return;
      }
      final List<Product> data = [];
      jsonData.forEach((prodId, productData) {
        data.add(
          Product(
            id: prodId,
            title: productData['title'],
            description: productData['description'],
            price: productData['price'],
            isFavourite: productData['favourite'],
            imageUrl: productData['imageUrl'],
          ),
        );
      });
      _items = data;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

and here is debug
[image]

the debug show [throw error] there is a problem here

Comment: Please don't post Images of Sourcecode and (if possible) of error messages.

Comment: Please take the time to post your code as markdown-formatted text rather than linking to screenshots.  Screenshots cannot be indexed by search engines, and will typically disappear in the future, making answers to this question useless to those that come along later.  Stack Overflow is a community site, where questions and answers hopefully benefit *multiple* users.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds sorry i am a beginner i edit the question

Comment: @marsh-wiggle I edit the question

Comment: Try removing the `try-catch`, bc currently you are just catching and throwing it again. When you remove the try-catch. Dart tools in VSCode will show you the exact line where the error occurred.

Comment: I delete try and catch and debug shows the error at line `title: productData['title'],` and the type of product model is `string` @TalhaBalaj

Answer (score 0):

The error is exactly what it says. You are expecting a type `int` at a field and the json response of the server is giving you a `String`. As I haven't seen the json response being returned by the server you'll have to go through your Product model and see what are the `int` type fields and make sure the json response for them is of type `int` as well.

Seeing your Product model, it can either be `id` or `price` field. I'm quite certain that price field of the server response is the issue as `id` fields are mostly `int` type in response. You would either have to make the `price` field of Product model a `String` or change the server code to return a `int` at ["price"].

You would need to change the type from `int` to `String` at this line `price: productData['price'],` most probably as a quick fix.

Hope that fixes your error :)

Comment: I delete try and catch and debug shows the error at line `title: productData['title'],` and the type of product model is `string`